# Why am I not able to delete my browser history anymore on my Mozilla firefox pc

Tags: browser, browser-history

Until yesterday I was able to go to history and click delete to delete my browsing history. Now I do the same and NOTHING is deleted when I press delete. How can this be fixed?

My browsing history delete function is not working